# Why is the limit of $\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}(x)$, zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

While studying I came across this function:

$$k_n:=\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}(x),\qquad n\geq1.$$
and apparently 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{1}_{\{x\in[n,n+1]\}}(x)=0,\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}$$

the limit is zero.
Could somebody please explain why this is true?

Comment: This holds because $x$ is fixed somewhere on the real line, so your measuring interval passes by at some point.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{1}_{\{x\in[n,n+1]\}}(x)$ is absurd and should be replaced by $\mathbb{1}_{x\in[n,n+1]}$ or $\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}(x)$.

Comment: The main thing to realize is that in taking this limit, you fix $x$ and let $n$ run. So no matter how large $x$ is, it will eventually be left behind as $n$ races to infinity. So the tail of the sequence of values is always eventually zero.

Comment: What does mean $k_n:=\mathbb{1}_{[n,n+1]}(x),\qquad n\geq1$ ????

Comment: @Piquito It's supposed to represent an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) on the interval $[n,n+1]$ for  a given integer $n$. Fixing $n\in \Bbb N$, it is defined for $x\in \Bbb R$ as $1_{[n,n+1]}(x)=\begin{cases}1 \quad \text{ if } x\in [n,n+1] \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Answer (score 2):

As $n\to \infty$ the archimidean property of the reals means that $\exists N\in \Bbb N$ s.t. $N>x_0$ for a fixed $x_0$.

Thus for all $n>N$ we have that $\Bbb 1_{x\in[n,n+1]}(x_0)=0$ since $x_0<n$. This holds for any $x_0$, and thus this gives a slightly informal argument as to why the limit is the zero function, via pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N > x$. For all $n \geq N$, we have $n > x$, so $x \notin [n,n+1]$, and therefore $1_{[n,n+1]}(x) = 0$. To reiterate, for all $n \geq N$ we have $1_{[n,n+1]}(x) = 0$. Therefore $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1_{[n,n+1]}(x) = 0$.

In terms of $\epsilon$-$N$: For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that for all positive integers $n \geq N$ we have
$$
|1_{[n,n+1]}(x) - 0| = 0 < \epsilon.
$$

Follow-Up Question (if you know about uniform convergence):  Does $1_{[n,n+1]}(x)$ converge to $0$ uniformly for $x \in \mathbb{R}$?